# Which instrument is used in beginning of Make you mine (by Public)

Tags: piano, acoustic-guitar, guitar-effects, bass-guitar, digital-piano

In the very beginning of sound I hear piano and hi hat probably, but there is still a 3rd humming kind of sound which follows the chords I think what is it?
I'm trying to make cover for the song and I  need to know what kind of instrument it is, or atleast I need to know how to and where to look if I want to understand about various instrument sounds in music I hear. Because I cannot recognise instruments many times.

I'm new for this site, apologies if I have framed my question poorly.
:)

I play guitar and classical piano but am very new to digital piano and yet can't recognise if this sound was actually made using synthetic piano.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on MusicFans. The post has been flagged so that the mods can migrate it.

Comment: @Aaron identification questions are now all off-topic on music fans.

Comment: @Dom Oh, cool. I thought they were just being more sharply restricted.

Comment: Welcome to this site. If you read the Help Centre, it'll give you better guidance for posing questions.

Comment: Then how shall I approach these areas of music as I'm still learning music but I'd like to explore and kmow more about music already made

Comment: It's a fine question, it's just that Stack Overflow isn't the place for it. I'd suggest asking in other music-oriented communities (Reddit? Maybe real-life friends?). Meanwhile, 1) Don't worry, as you get more experience you'll get better at analyzing what you hear, and 2) As DataProcessing mentions, a cover doesn't have to be *exactly* the same as the original. If you want to include these sounds in your version, try various instruments and see what you think sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

Electric guitar, but you don't need to precisely copy the original arrangement in order to do a cover.  Some of the best known cover songs don't try to stick close to what the original artist did.  Of course if you're new and just trying to learn music arrangement and pop song construction, then it can be very instructive to figure out what all the parts are and what they're doing.  But eventually you'll want to do it your own way.

Comment: I believe the OP refers to that "humming" as the "wobbling" sound other than the guitar. It *might* be a guitar effect, but it's probably a synth with an LFO linked to the volume.